# Проблема при компиляции под Android TLS initialization failed в QT

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml, qt6

Проблема заключается в том что при компиляции под Android в qt (проект QT-Quick). При попытке любого подключения (HTTP/HTTPS) выводит ошибку  "TLS initialization failed", но при том же коде и компиляции под Desktop запрос отправляется без проблем. Так же, для компиляции под Android подключено все и там нету никаких проблем. Если не входить в сеть все работает отлично. На самом устройстве дано разрешения для входа в сеть.
вот все файлы в которых я работал и настройка компиляции под Android
[image: Настройка компиляции]
[image: SSH]

CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.1)

option(LINK_INSIGHT "Link Qt Insight Tracker library" ON)
option(BUILD_QDS_COMPONENTS "Build design studio components" ON)

project(aApp LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Добавьте опции компиляции
add_compile_options("-D_SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS" "-Wno-everything")

find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Qml Quick Network)

if (Qt6_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 6.3)
    qt_standard_project_setup()
endif()

qt_add_executable(aApp src/main.cpp
)

qt_add_resources(aApp "configuration"
    PREFIX "/"
    FILES
        qtquickcontrols2.conf
)

target_link_libraries(aApp PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Qml
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Network  # Добавляем Network
)

if (BUILD_QDS_COMPONENTS)
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qmlcomponents)
endif()

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qmlmodules)

if (LINK_INSIGHT)
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/insight)
endif ()

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS aApp
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QObject>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
//#include <SFML/Network.hpp> думал что проблема в самом QT и подключал ещё SFML

#include "app_environment.h"
#include "import_qml_components_plugins.h"
#include "import_qml_plugins.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    set_qt_environment();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:Main/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(
        &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app,
        [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);

    engine.addImportPath(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/qml");
    engine.addImportPath(":/");

    engine.load(url);

    // Создаем менеджер для сетевых запросов
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    // Создаем запрос
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://www.snp.kiev.ua/SmartHouse.php?pasword=get temp
    &who=client&request=123456&Arguments=789"));

    // Выполняем GET-запрос
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(request);

    // Обработка ответа на запрос
    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [&]() {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
            qDebug() << "Response:" << data;
        } else {
            qDebug() << "HTTP request failed with error:" << reply->errorString();
        }
        reply->deleteLater();
    });


    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15


ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: "Smarthouse"

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: mainPageComponent
    }

    Component {
        id: mainPageComponent

        Item {


            Button {

                id: settingsButton // Додали id для кнопки налаштувань
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                width: 50
                height: 50



                onClicked: {
                    stackView.push(settingsPageComponent)
                }
            }

            // Текстове поле
            Text {
                id: mainText
                anchors.top: settingsButton.bottom
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                text: qsTr("Your text here")
                font.pixelSize: 24
            }

            // Колонка кнопок
            Column {
                anchors.top: mainText.bottom
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                spacing: 10

                Button {
                    text: qsTr("Температура дому")
                    onClicked: {
                        // ...
                    }
                }

                Button {
                                   text: qsTr("Полив")
                                   onClicked: {
                                       stackView.push(wateringPageComponent)
                                   }
                               }

                Button {
                    text: qsTr("Охорона")
                    onClicked: {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Сторінка для "Полив"
    Component {
        id: wateringPageComponent

        Item {
            id: wateringPage

            Button {
                text: "Назад"
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                onClicked: {
                    stackView.pop()
                }
            }

            // Вертикальна колонка для елементів
            Column {
                anchors.left: parent.left // Вирівнюємо елементи по лівому краю
                anchors.leftMargin: 50
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter // Вертикально по центру
                spacing: 10  // Відступ між елементами

                Text {
                    text: "Показники датчиків"
                    // Вирівнювання тексту тепер не потрібно, оскільки колонка вирівнює елементи
                }

                Text {
                    text: "Д 1 - значення"
                }

                Text {
                    text: "Д 2 - значення"
                }

                Button {
                    text: "Налаштування часу"
                    onClicked: {
                        // Ваш код тут
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    text: "Розклад поливу"
                    onClicked: {
                        // Ваш код тут
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    text: "Журнал поливу"
                    onClicked: {
                        onClicked: {
                            stackView.push(wateringJournalPageComponent)
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Компонент для сторінки "Журнал поливу"
    Component {
        id: wateringJournalPageComponent

        Item {
            id: wateringJournalPage

            Button {
                text: "Назад"
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                onClicked: {
                    stackView.pop()
                }
            }

            Text {
                text: "Журнал\nполиву"
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 30
                 anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }

            Row {
                       anchors.top: parent.top
                       anchors.topMargin: 90
                       anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                       spacing: window.width * 0.2

                       Text { text: "Дата"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter }
                       Text { text: "Час"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter }
                       Text { text: "Д1"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter }
                       Text { text: "Д2"; horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter }
                   }

                   Rectangle {
                       id: dataTable
                       anchors.top: parent.top
                       anchors.topMargin: 130
                       anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                       width: parent.width * 0.9
                       height: parent.height * 0.5
                       border.color: "black"

                       GridLayout {
                           columns: 4

                           Repeater {
                               model: yourDataModel

                               Text {
                                   text: modelData.date
                                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                                   verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                                   leftPadding: 10
                               }
                               Text {
                                   text: modelData.time
                                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                                   verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                               }
                               Text {
                                   text: modelData.d1
                                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                                   verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                               }
                               Text {
                                   text: modelData.d2
                                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                                   verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }


                    // Додати рядки з даними тут
                }

}

    Component {
        id: settingsPageComponent

        Item {
            id: settingsPage

            Button {
                       text: "Назад"
                       anchors.top: parent.top
                       anchors.left: parent.left
                       onClicked: {
                           stackView.pop()
                       }
            }
            // Вертикальна колонка для вирівнювання по центру
                   Column {
                       anchors.centerIn: parent  // Центруємо колонку в батьківському елементі
                       spacing: 10  // Відступ між елементами

                       Text {
                           text: "Налаштування підключення"
                           horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter  // Вирівнювання тексту по горизонталі
                       }

                       // Горизонтальний рядок для кнопок
                       Row {
                           spacing: 10  // Відступ між кнопками

                           Button {
                               text: "СМС"
                               onClicked: {
                                   // Логіка для налаштування СМС
                               }
                           }

                           Button {
                               text: "Інтернет"
                               onClicked: {
                                   // Логіка для налаштування Інтернету
                               }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.qtproject.example"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_CODE%% --"
    android:versionName="-- %%INSERT_VERSION_NAME%% --">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <supports-screens
    
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
    <application
        android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:allowNativeHeapPointerTagging="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupOnly="false">
        <activity
            android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density"
            android:label="-- %%INSERT_APP_NAME%% --"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

          <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --" />

          <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.arguments"
                android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_ARGUMENTS%% --" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.extract_android_style"
                android:value="minimal" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.qtprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/qtprovider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```